# create margins after page break within tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

Im working on a Report with a coverpage. So the body has no margins and the full page is useable.
The report also has no Headers or footers because the coverpage must cover the whole page.
For tablix i set a row with empty textboxes to get white space between the page border and the tablix. But if a tablix gets so much data that 1 site is not enough, the data will go to the very edge of the page and start at the very top of the new page.

How can i enter space at these points so data isnt at the edge of the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a method that worked in this case.
So the BackEnd dev requested for me to split the two reports into the Coverpage and visual data area. That way i can have footers and my colleague simply merges both reports back together when its being requested.